# How to stop Selenium on clicking span element

Tags: selenium

Following is the element

```
<a href="#" class="finalLevel showMenuElement" data-index="8,2,5" title="Workitem Summary"  data-wintitle="Workitem Summary">Workitem Summary<span id="fav" class="addtoFav"></span></a>
```

I want to click on link text "Workitem summary", but it seems that Selenium is clicking on `id="fav"` element, instead.

How can I tell Selenium to click on `Linktext "Workitem Summary"` and not on the span element?

These both elements are next to each other.

I even tried **XPath**, same results

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Workitem Summary")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"2\"]/li[5]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Post your html code.

Comment: The `<span>` is a child node of the `<a>` node. Why would you want to avoid considering the `<span>`? What is your usecase exactly?

Comment: Span is part of the link, if you want to add this link in your favorite link , you use span. But as I want to open the link, I would like to avoid span

Answer (score 0):

Text between  tag is "**Workitem Summary**", So if you would use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Workitem Summary")).click();
```

that hyperlink will be clicked.

Span is anyway in between the anchor tag.

you can have something like that :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Workitem Summary']")).click()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but result is still the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking with offset (click on the x-y coordinate distance in pixels from the top left corner):

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Workitem Summary']");
Actions build = new Actions(driver);
build.moveToElement(myElement, X-offset, Y-offset).click().build().perform();
```

Enter corresponding values (in pixels) for X-offset and Y-offset.

EDIT:

OP was able to solve the problem with the following code:

```
WebElement add1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Workitem Summary")); 
int width = add1.getSize().getWidth(); 
Actions act = new Actions(driver); 
act.moveToElement(add1).moveByOffset((width / 2) - 2, 0).click().perform(); 
add1.click();
```

Comment: What x-y values did you use? Try with low values (like 2 px).

Comment: Values were 254 and 171

Comment: That is too much. That would almost certainly click outside of the element. Try with 5 and 5 pixels.

Comment: it did something, let me explain
so from a top left I have a Menu, I click it it gives something like this :
A 
B
C
D
E

Now Clicking on A, shows screen as and similarly to other menu items
A A1
B A2
C A3
D
E

I want to click on E-E4, trying this 5,5 , it actually navigated to E-E4, but the link that got clicked was D-D4, both E-E4 and D-D4 will share the same coordinate, so we are close to fix it :)

Comment: Try using negative values for y. Like "-5".

Comment: Same results with -5

Comment: What is the HTML of the E-E4 element?

Comment: Copy OuterHTML
<a href="#" class="finalLevel" data-index="8,2,5" title="Workitem Summary" data-comp="CTGUI" data-domainid="bancs" data-funcid="100080" data-mode="undefined" data-preload="true" data-winname="ct_w_StatList_CASL" data-wintitle="Workitem Summary">Workitem Summary<span id="fav" class="addtoFav"></span></a>

Comment: Try adding these lines: `WebElement myOtherElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-comp='CTGUI']"); build.moveToElement(myOtherElement).click().build().perform();`.

Comment: it again clicked, D-D4 link

Comment: I tried all this with Chrome driver now, was using IE before. In all the cases, offset or data comp, result is , its still clicking id=fav element

Comment: Can you please post the HTML of the relevant part of the page, but with "A" clicked and E-E4 and D-D4 shown?

Comment: I did some hit and trial, and I think issue is something different, driver is able to click on E-E1 and E-E3, just by giving "LinkText" , but fails to click E-E2 and E-E4, I compared the HTML tags of all 4 , there is no difference other then tagname, is it something to do with odd-even?

Comment: It is impossible to tell without the HTML.

Comment: Got the solution , 
WebElement add1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Workitem Summary"));
            int width = add1.getSize().getWidth();
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.moveToElement(add1).moveByOffset((width / 2) - 2, 0).click().perform();
            add1.click();

Comment: Good to hear that.

Comment: Thanks Mate, for helping out

Comment: No problem. I'll edit my answer with your comment, and you can upvote and accept it if you found it useful.